# Cloudformation: How do I setup multiple dns entries using AWS::Route53::RecordSet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I am using this cloudformation fragment to map my elb to a domain name:

```
 "dnsRecord" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
     "Properties" : {
         "HostedZoneName" : "apps.acme.com.",
         "Comment" : "DNS name for instance.",
         "Name" : {
             "Fn::Join" : [ "", [
                 {"Ref" : "Hostname"}, "."
             ]]
         },
         "Type" : "CNAME",
         "TTL" : "900",
         "ResourceRecords" : [
             { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ElasticLoadBalancer", "DNSName" ] }
         ]
     }
 }
```

I need to be able to setup many names or aliases for this elb using cloudformation, using a parameter.  I am thinking of a CSV string as the parameter, but am not clear how to "iterate" over that CSV string to repeat this "dnsRecord" block as many times as required.

For example, if Hostname was "fred.apps.acme.com,bertha.apps.acme.com", that would setup 2 dns entries for me to the same elb.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iteration over the CloudFormation wouldn't be of much help; actually not possible. You can write CFN template to finish all the necessary Stack Resources and use the User Script or Custom Start Script [ in python or Shell Script ] to iterate the necessary DNS Setting.

You can make use of Depends-On & Wait-Handle to introduce the time delay in the stack while the ELB gets created.

Answer (score 0):

There's no concept of iterating over a CSV passed in as a parameter. Further, the ability to iterate implies that the list size will not be known before the stack is created. CloudFormation requires that each resource be explicitly defined. This means that you can't pass a variable sized list and have an AWS::Route53::RecordSet resource created for each element in the list.

Because each domain name will need its own AWS::Route53::RecordSet resource, you'll need to edit the template if you need to add or remove domains.

In this situation, I'd recommend creating a new AWS::Route53::RecordSet for each domain name that you want to map to your ELB.